# SDL game doesn't work properly without cout

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm C++ beginner, and I am currently following a tutorial to make a game with SDL2. In the process of configurating delta time to allow user control of an object, I seem to have a problem with the smoothness of the object's movement: it is only smooth when cout is added, without which the object seems almost unresponsive.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
int objectDir;
int Input() {
        const Uint8* state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
        objectDir = 0;
        if(state[SDL_SCANCODE_W]) {
            objectDir -=1;
        }
        if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_S]) {
            objectDir += 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
int Update() {
        if (objectDir != 0) {
            objectPos.y += objectDir*50*deltaTime;
        }
        return 0;
}
int Loop() {
        while (gameRunning)
        {
            if (!SDL_TICKS_PASSED(SDL_GetTicks(), tick + 0.033f)) {continue;}
            deltaTime = SDL_GetTicks() - tick;
            if (deltaTime > 0.05f) {
                deltaTime = 0.05f;
            }
            Input();
            Update();
            Output();
            tick = SDL_GetTicks();
        }
        return 0;
    }
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Loop();
}
```

I've tried removing the conditional line (SDL_TICKS_PASSED()), but nothing changed.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and run that through an auto formatter (most IDEs have one built in). As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: In other words, we want something we can actually compile, run, and see the same problem as you do. (But we also want all irrelevant parts removed from it, if possible.)

Comment: `while (gameRunning) { if (!SDL_TICKS_PASSED(SDL_GetTicks(), tick + 0.033f)) {continue;}` that's a very tight loop which gives  away no control. Output to standard stream is  usually synchronized to other terminal i/o, which creates some steady pauses in execution. It's implementation- and platform-related  so one cannot rely on it. It's still a very busy loop because that output happens only when time is reached. I bet you get very high CPU usage from that process.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'll try to improve.
@Swift-FridayPie's reply seemed to help me understand the problem. It turns out 0.033 is in ms so the loop was indeed very tight.

Comment: @tsuanorm Yeah, that's  33 microseconds. On most systems  the precision is millisecond unless special timing techniques are used, e.g. a "multimedia timer". In realtime systems (like a plane\drone autopilot) it may go down to 300-200 microsconds, any less you need special hardware  and OS solutions. You literally had 0 time but becuase OS is involved, it was unsteady , skipping beat. Games don't do this since late-90s.

Comment: Solutions used in games often are the most obvious one:  don't do an empty loop iteration. Always DO sothing whihc got fixed time execution or you'll have problems. That's why games like Skyrim are linked to fixed framerate - simple, dirty and portable solution unless user does something unprecedented, like disabling framerate limiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the return value of [`SDL_GetTicks()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_GetTicks): it returns an *integer* value representing the number of *millisecond* that have passed since the start of the program. It doesn't return a floating point number.

Basically, your `if (!SDL_TICKS_PASSED(SDL_GetTicks(), tick + 0.033f)) {continue;}` statement will cause it to wait at most one millisecond. Then afterwards, `deltaTime = SDL_GetTicks() - tick` will for sure be equal to 1 or to an even larger integer. So then you *always* cap `deltaTtime` to 0.05, regardless of how much time actually passed.

Printing to `std::cout` might take a bit more than 1 millisecond perhaps, which allows more ticks to pass between iterations of your `while`-loop, which causes your game to behave differently. To fix it, make sure you interpret `SDL_GetTicks()` correctly.

One more issue: `Input()`, `Update()` and `Output()` take some variable time to complete. If you call `tick = SDL_GetTicks()` at the end of the `while`-loop, that means you will then wait for a fixed amount of time after `Output()` returned. So your frame period will be that fixed amount *plus* the variable amount caused by the aforementioned functions. To get a steady framerate, there are options:

1. Rely on vertical sync.
2. Write a loop that looks like this:

   ```
   const Uint32 frame_time = 50; // 50 ms per frame
   Uint32 next_frame = SDL_GetTicks();

   while (gameRunning) {
       if (!SDL_TICKS_PASSED(SDL_GetTicks(), next_frame)) {continue;}
       …
       next_frame += frame_time;
   }
   ```

Last but not least, you are doing a [busy loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) waiting for the next frame. That will use 100% CPU time unnecessarily, causing more power usage and increasing the temperature of the CPU. Again, either rely on vertical sync, or use [`SDL_Delay()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_Delay) to sleep until it's time for the next frame.

Comment: Very informative. Thank you for the answer.